# how to convert json file to csv with "success":true

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv, url

I have problem with convert json file to csv file on python
and i think it will be the nested json file but i don't know how to handle it!

```
    import json, requests 

url = requests.get("https://####/api/food_orders")
text = url.text

data = json.load(text)
 
    order_data = data['data']

    # now we will open a file for writing
    data_file = open('ordersJsonToCsv.csv', 'w', newline='')

    # create the csv writer object
    csv_writer = csv.writer(data_file)

    # Counter variable used for writing
    # headers to the CSV file
    count = 0

    for ord in order_data:
        if count == 0:

            # Writing headers of CSV file
            header = ord.keys()
            csv_writer.writerow(header)
            count += 1

        # Writing data of CSV file
        csv_writer.writerow(ord.values())

    data_file.close()
```

And Json file look like
[image]

Comment: Post text not images

Comment: {"success":true,"data":[{"id":317,"price":10,"quantity":2,"food_id":44,"order_id":130},
{"id":317,"price":10,"quantity":2,"food_id":44,"order_id":130},
{"id":317,"price":10,"quantity":2,"food_id":44,"order_id":130}]}

Comment: The json looks fine (consider we don't know what's in the CSV). So, what's the issue?

Comment: the issue i want to get only the data and convert it to csv file and the code doesn't work

Comment: read only this part (data":[{"id":317,"price":10,"quantity":2,"food_id":44,"order_id":130}, {"id":317,"price":10,"quantity":2,"food_id":44,"order_id":130}, {"id":317,"price":10,"quantity":2,"food_id":44,"order_id":130}]) 
from json using python

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: i give the code above! and the problem with i can't read  data only using this code

Answer (score 0):

This code will solve the problem to get data only

import pandas as pd
import json, requests

```
url = requests.get("https://##/api/orders?
text = url.text

info = json.loads(text)

df = pd.json_normalize(info['data'])

df.to_csv("samplecsv.csv")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).